# Sidekiq parent batch not waiting for child batches

Tags: sidekiq

UPDATE: Realizing now this is Sidekiq Pro only feature. No wonder it wasn't working.

I'm creating a parent batch, then within that creating child batches, but the parent job is "completing" before the children finish.

I'm doing what the docs say, the only difference that I can tell is that I'm not creating the child batches directly within a Sidekiq worker, but within a class called by the worker.

But I'm passing the batch through and have confirmed that the child batches have a batch.parent_bid that matches the initial overall batch.

When I watch Sidekiq web, I see the parent worker finish way before all the children, but I need it to wait. Ideas?

Code looks something like this:

```
overall = Sidekiq::Batch.new
overall.jobs do
    ParentWorker.perform_async current_user.id
end


class ParentWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker

  def perform user_id
    user = User.find(user_id)
    UserPopulator.new.import_all user, batch
  end

end

class UserPopulator

  def initialize user, batch
    @user = user
    @batch = batch
  end

  def import_all
    overall = Sidekiq::Batch.new(@batch.bid)
    overall.jobs do
      child_batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
      user.friends.each do |friend|
        child_batch.jobs do
          GetFriends.perform_async @user_id, friend
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: https://github.com/chaps-io/gush

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "wait" for other jobs to finish is to define a callback that is executed when all of the jobs within that batch are finished.  Since you haven't defined any, you won't get that behavior.  Review the Batches wiki page.

```
batch.on(:success, ...)
```